# Como manipular o MAC address(endereço fisico) do roteadot?

Tags: php, java, html5, intel-xdk

Estou fazendo um aplicativo no INTEL XDK para smartphone e gostaria de capturar o valor do MAC Adrees do Roteador Wifi ativo no momento, assim como o nome da rede (SSID) e senha, para fazer comparações. Exemplo: tenho 3 roteadores com o mesmo nome e senha, porém com os VALORES DOS MACs 'A', 'B' e 'C' respectivamente no meu trabalho e quero que quando eu estiver conectado ao Roteador com MAC Adrees = 'B' o aplicativo habilite algumas funções e me informe que estou conectado no Roteador com SSID = 'trabalho', Senha = 'senha' e MAC = 'B'.
Como manipular o MAC Adrees (endereço físico) do roteador?

Comment: Não tenho certeza se o html5 faz isso...

Comment: não precisa ser especificamente o html5, vou utilizar esses dados em um app, casa saiba em outra linguagem serve.

Comment: Na verdade não é possível obter essa informação, com exceção do IE... Edite sua pergunta e adicione as tags `java`, `javascript`, `php` e mais a que vier na sua mente, quem sabe existe alguém como uma solução... Isso é tipo ver o tipo "sanguíneo" do usuário, não creio ser tão simples...Existem alguns algorítimos de rede, de baixo-nível, que abrangem essas técnicas... Mas é bem complexo... Por que além da camada de aplicação, você terá que ter um certo domínio sobre as outras 6...

Comment: Apesar que acho que me confundi,,, É um App nativo, então acho que dá...

Comment: Tentastes algum código, para essas tarefas ?

Answer (score 0):

Oh, tem essa solução em Java :

```
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.NetworkInterface;
import java.net.SocketException;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;

public class App{

   public static void main(String[] args){

    InetAddress ip;
    try {

        ip = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
        System.out.println("Current IP address : " + ip.getHostAddress());

        NetworkInterface network = NetworkInterface.getByInetAddress(ip);

        byte[] mac = network.getHardwareAddress();

        System.out.print("Current MAC address : ");

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < mac.length; i++) {
            sb.append(String.format("%02X%s", mac[i], (i < mac.length - 1) ? "-" : ""));        
        }
        System.out.println(sb.toString());

    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();

    } catch (SocketException e){

        e.printStackTrace();

    }

   }

}
```

Veja se lhe ajuda.

[Fonte](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-get-mac-address-in-java/)

Comment: complementado a resposta teria que criar um client e server socket dhcp para saber o gateway da rede e ai sim pegar o mac do router

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/828017/How-do-run-a-DHCP-java-code

Comment: Boa...Pow formula uma resposta aí, não achei nenhuma completa aqui no SOpt,,,

Comment: Testei todos os códigos diponibilizados, porém, todos me retornam o Mac da máquina e não do ROTEADOR, como criar um client e server socket dhcp para me retornar essa informação? @Assanges, como o MagicHat falou, também não achei nenhuma resposta completa, se poder postar agradeceria muito.